# Create table error in Valentina Studio

Tags: sqlite, permissions, valentina-studio

I am unable to create a table in Valentina Studio in my sqlite database.

Using another application called Datum, I am able to open the sqlite database 'data.db' and run the query 'CREATE TABLE a(b INT, c INT)' successfully.

When I open Valentina Studio and click on the database in the first window and then click on the green plus sign with 'Create' listed to the right, a dialog box pops up. The title bar of the dialog box says 'Create Table' and in the table tab when I type 'table1' beside 'Name' and add a field named 'dog' under the Fields tab and press the 'Create' button then I get an error. The error says 'Sqlite db "/[path-to-file]/data.db": Error : "unable to open database file"' (It doesn't really say [path-to-file], this is just an alias for the path on my filesystem).

I am the primary user of this computer and write/read permissions are enabled for me on 'data.db' and on the folder that contains 'data.db' for me. I am using a Mac Book Pro.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you are using MAS edition of Valentina Studio?

According to MAS/Apple rules, such app works in sandbox mode,
to work with db files located e.g. on the desktop or other folders, 
you need at first once Allow Access. You can do this in 
[Preferences Dialog - Allowed Locations Help](http://valentina-db.com/docs/dokuwiki/v7/doku.php?id=valentina:products:vstudio:help:dialogs:preferences:allowed_locations)

Normal (not MAS) edition of Valentina Studio for Mac do not require this step.